# Send mail php with a .live email

Tags: php, smtp, html-email

I can send a email to my domain email but when using a .live email as the $to in php I get the error in the log "Denied ATTR36" is there anything I can do Thanks

Comment: Check on microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/relay-access-denied-smtp

Comment: First you search for the error message, then you digest what it says. Then you realise that the recieveing somain does not like the sensing domain. Quite a regular occurance noadays See [ms docs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/admin-center/550-5-7-64-relay-access-denied-attr36/m-p/730684)